# Why is the following error message popping up despite me having the correct version: "AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'get_user_token'

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-active-directory

With the use of this tutorial, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/python?tabs=aad, where I'm trying to get a Python app to function properly. It uses the Microsoft Graph API to access data on behalf of a user and is supposed to work, but it isn't working for me.

This is the following error message that pops up:

[image]

These are the files that I have:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Main:

[image]

[image]

When I press 1 it is supposed to prompt me to log in. I initially thought it was due to me using the wrong Python version, but even though I'm using the same version as in the tutorial, the same problem shows up. I'm using Python version 3.10.4 and pip version 20.0.2.

Comment: Hello. Please, do not post code as image.

Comment: The error is expectable. Your class ´Graph´ does not have any function named ´get_user_token()´. What did you expect to happen when you call ´graph.get_user_token()´ ?

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to reproduce same process in my environment and got same error:**

**Console:**
[image]

- After I refer the document which you have posted in question and made changes with version of **`python, pip and msgraph-sdk`** because in **`msgraph-sdk`** they are using **`1.0.0a2.`** as per document.
- Make sure your graph is authenticating with your user.

Use the command:

```
  Pip install msgraph-sdk==1.0.0a2
```

**graph. py**:

```
from configparser import SectionProxy
from kiota_authentication_azure.azure_identity_authentication_provider import (
    AzureIdentityAuthenticationProvider)
from msgraph import GraphRequestAdapter, GraphServiceClient
from msgraph.generated.me.me_request_builder import MeRequestBuilder
from msgraph.generated.me.mail_folders.item.messages.messages_request_builder import (
    MessagesRequestBuilder)
from msgraph.generated.me.send_mail.send_mail_post_request_body import SendMailPostRequestBody
from msgraph.generated.models.message import Message
from msgraph.generated.models.item_body import ItemBody
from msgraph.generated.models.body_type import BodyType
from msgraph.generated.models.recipient import Recipient
from msgraph.generated.models.email_address import EmailAddress
from async_auth import AsyncDeviceCodeCredential

class Graph:
    settings: SectionProxy
    device_code_credential: AsyncDeviceCodeCredential
    adapter: GraphRequestAdapter
    user_client: GraphServiceClient

    def __init__(self, config: SectionProxy):
        self.settings = config
        client_id = self.settings['clientId']
        tenant_id = self.settings['tenantId']
        graph_scopes = self.settings['graphUserScopes'].split(' ')

        self.device_code_credential = AsyncDeviceCodeCredential(client_id, tenant_id = tenant_id)
        auth_provider = AzureIdentityAuthenticationProvider(
            self.device_code_credential,
            scopes=graph_scopes)
        self.adapter = GraphRequestAdapter(auth_provider)
        self.user_client = GraphServiceClient(self.adapter)
# </UserAuthConfigSnippet>

    # <GetUserTokenSnippet>
    async def get_user_token(self):
        graph_scopes = self.settings['graphUserScopes']
        access_token = await self.device_code_credential.get_token(graph_scopes)
        return access_token.token
```

**main. py**

```
import asyncio
import configparser
from graph import Graph

async def main():
    print('Python Graph Tutorial\n')

    # Load settings
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read(['config.cfg', 'config.dev.cfg'])
    azure_settings = config['azure']

    graph: Graph = Graph(azure_settings)

    await greet_user(graph)

    choice = -1

    while choice != 0:
        print('Please choose one of the following options:')
        print('0. Exit')
        print('1. Display access token')
        print('2. List my inbox')
        print('3. Send mail')
        print('4. Make a Graph call')

        try:
            choice = int(input())
        except ValueError:
            choice = -1

        if choice == 0:
            print('Goodbye...')
        elif choice == 1:
            await display_access_token(graph)
        elif choice == 2:
            await list_inbox(graph)
        elif choice == 3:
            await send_mail(graph)
        elif choice == 4:
            await make_graph_call(graph)
        else:
            print('Invalid choice!\n')

async def greet_user(graph: Graph):
    # TODO
    return

async def display_access_token(graph: Graph):
    token = await graph.get_user_token()
    print('User token:', token, '\n')

async def list_inbox(graph: Graph):
    # TODO
    return

async def send_mail(graph: Graph):
    # TODO
    return

async def make_graph_call(graph: Graph):
    # TODO
    return

asyncio.run(main())
```

**Console:**
After I made changes in code the code executed perfectly and I got sign in link.

[image]

After signing in through web I can able to get the access token successfully.

[image]

**Reference:**
[microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-python: Completed project for Build Python apps with Microsoft Graph (github.com)](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-python)